# Plot euclidian points in R from data frame

Tags: r, plot

Having a data frame with two columns, one for the x-coordinate and one for the y-coordinate, how to plot the points from the data frame?

Attempted code so far:

```
plot(dataFrame);


plot(dataFrame$x, dataFrame$y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, you can just call the plot function. A sample matrix:

```
data <- cbind(x = 1:10, y = runif(10))
class(data)
## [1] "matrix"

plot(data)
```

---

This also works for a data frame.

```
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10))
plot(data)
```

---

In general, (where there are more than two columns), you usually want to use `with`.

```
with(data, plot(x, y))
```

Comment: @AndreiI Same answer works for both.

Comment: I have no idea why, but when I initially tried the plot() command directly with the data frame, it did not work, which right now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Say your data frame is called `data` and the columns are `data$x` and `data$y`.

```
dataStruct <- structure(list(x = data$x, y = data$y), .Names = c("x", "y"))
plot(dataStruct)
```